# How I can change the Background in runtime in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to make a simple program with 2 Radiobutton (`rd1 and rd2`), what can change background to picture s1, or s2, depend on what was selected. How I can make it? I tried background.setBackground (background is my RadioGroup's name), but it didn't work.

Comment: What background are you trying to change?  Android wallpaper?  The activity's main view's background?  Or the radio group's background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for changing android wallpaper.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/SetWallpaperActivity.html

and if you want change the background for the current activity means

if your layout is lay means then,

```
lay.BackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.abc);
```

in onClick listenerof ur radio button

sure it will help you dude..let me know what happened...

Thank you.